# Numpy 3D Transformation on list of 2

Tags: python, numpy

I have a transformation matrix for 2D Points, which thus has a shape (3, 3). For instance:

```
array([[2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

**Edit:** This is only an example. The actual transformation can contain translation and thus must have this size.

and I have a list of 2D Points with shape (<number_of_point>, 2), which I would like to transform with the transformation matrix.

The multiplication should be with the matrix on the left. So

```
my_matrix @ my_point
```

I think to make this work in numpy I need two things:

- Transpose the 2d point list
- Make all 2d points three dimensional by adding a z value of 1 to each point

How can I do this in an easy way with numpy?

The result should be a list of 2d points again like the input. So pseudo code might be something like:

```
(matrix @ points.T.add_z_dimension()).T[:-1]
```

where it would transpose points, add the z dimension with a value of 1, do the transposition, transform it back and slice the z dimension.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the matrix is `M` and your list of vectors is `v`, the simplest solution would be:

```py
(M @ np.hstack((v, np.ones((v.shape[0], 1)))).T).T[..., :2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform exactly what you describe, you can use the [`numpy.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) function in `'constant'` mode with the value 1.

```
padded_points = numpy.pad(points, [(0, 0), (0, 1)], mode='constant', constant_values=1)
```

Another option is to stack a vector of ones.

```
padded_points = numpy.hstack([points, numpy.ones((points.shape[0], 1))])
```

But your transformation does not seem very natural. If you have no dependence in the z dimension, you should rather consider the cropped version of your transformation matrix `my_matrix[:2, :2]`.

Comment: A transformation matrix always has one dimension more. How else would you do translations? The above example only contains scaling (thus a 2d matrix would be fine in that specific case), but for the general case which can contain scaling, rotations and translations three dimensions are needed.

Comment: Well no. It is one common way, in projective geometry, using homogeneous coordinates. But there is no rules saying "always". And you did not specify what kind of transform you want. For example, if these are projective transform, you also need to divide x and y by z. For the input data, that goes without saying, if z=1. For the result before dropping z, and switch back into cartesian coordinates, you need the divide. Of course, if you guarantee the last row of the matrix is ``0 0 1``, then, z is always 1 after the transform too. That is, it is just planar affine transform. But you didn't say.